Working in frontend JS. Is there a clean way to prevent all request response large integers from being rounded
I'm returning a dictionary object to a web route. And annoyingly, my frontend JS is automatically rounding all the integer values in the response.json()
let currentUserId;
let path = "/account?raw=True";
fetch(path)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
if (BigInt(data.id) != null) {

This means that data.id is being rounded and I need this value to remain as its exact form.
Is there a clean method for ensuring values aren't rounded, aside from doing data.id = BigInt(data.id) on every single ID or large integer value.

Send the numbers as strings, that's pretty much all you can do.

Why are you converting the ID to an integer in the first place? Just keep it as a string.

Well because the values are stored in my database as integers, and im compiling them into a dict to send to the frontend.

@rho the problem is that normal 64-bit integers (as you have clearly seen) overflow the accuracy of 64-bit floating point. Keep them as strings, and then if  you want you can turn the strings into BigInt values on the client.

I dont want to have to make them into BigInts at all. I just want to be able to take my backend integer values and read them straight off in JS without any rounding. But I will take all your advice and make user ID's unique strings instead of large integers on the server side.
